# An example for UIApplicationShortcutWidget in iOS with Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3dtouch

[image]

I need an example (in Objective C) for how to add `UIApplicationShortcutWidget` with `3D Touch Quick launch icon`. Image preview shows sample of Google maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need understood about app Extensions (Introduced from iOS 10).

Step 1.Just follow this tutorial https://www.appcoda.com/app-extension-programming-today

Step 2. Create today widget app extension(You can create upto n number of widgets).

Step 3. It will displyed on notication center of phone (Tutorial guides you.)

Step 4. Choose any one widget.Copy your widget with bundle id.

Step 5. Paste into your info.plist like UIApplicationShortcutWidget com.companyname.projectname.YourWidgetName

Step6. It will showed like below image [image]

Note :Only one widget will be shown in 3D Touch.So select any one to paste it on info.plist.

Final Step:Build and Run ,Your widget(App extension view) showed on phone notification center(swipe left or right edit option available,you can add/remove also manually for app extension view ).For 3D Touch just force touch the app icon ,it will show the widget on your top or bottom of the app icon based on icon position.

Comment: Step 5 should be unnecessary if you have only one widget- > "The bundle ID of the widget that's available as a Home screen quick action in apps that have more than one widget." https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiapplicationshortcutwidget